# How to deal with varying starting/ending key frames in D3 transitions

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to move some bars to create some space for then appearing bars (Event A). I am doing this with a rule: Bars adjacent to the hovered bar will move depending on how close they are. They will get back to their original locations upon mouseout (Event B). Both events calculate the new locations by taking the current location and adding to or subtracting from it.

I've got the basics running. However there is one tricky situation: Mouseout from BAR1 and Mouseover to BAR2 may occur too soon. It goes as follows:

1. Mouseover BAR5, Event A1 starts and ends peacefully. BAR6 is replaced.
2. Mouseout BAR5, Event B1 starts. BAR6 is moving back to its original place.
3. (Before B1 is completed) Mouseover Bar4, Event A2 starts.

Event A1 gets the current location from DOM (as explained [here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/#animation)) and this means that bars will have moved in an unwanted fashion, e.g. labels and bars are not aligned anymore.

Here is how I try to do this:

```
    svg.selectAll('rect')
    .on('mouseover', function() {
      var curr = this;
      var rects = d3.selectAll('.rect.FinalRank')
        .transition().duration(500);

      var ind = rects[0].indexOf(this);
      var arrLen = rects[0].length;

      rects.attr('y', function(d, i) {
          var gScale = d3.scale.pow().range([5, 0]);

          if (0 <= i && i < ind) {
            gScale.domain([0, ind])
              // //debugger
            return (+d3.select(this).attr('y') + gScale(ind - i))
          } else if (arrLen > i && i > ind) {
            gScale.domain([0, arrLen - ind - 1])
            return (+d3.select(this).attr('y') - gScale(i - ind))
          } else {
            return (d3.select(this).attr('y'))
          }
        });

      var dataObj = d3.select(this).datum();
    })

  .on('mouseout', function() {
    var curr = this;
    var rects = d3.selectAll('.rect.FinalRank')
      .transition('out').duration(500);

    var ind = rects[0].indexOf(this);
    var arrLen = rects[0].length

    var spaceGrad = d3.scale.pow().range([5, 0])

   rects.attr('y', function(d, i) {
      var gScale = d3.scale.pow().range([5, 0]);

      if (0 <= i && i < ind) {
        gScale.domain([0, ind])
          //debugger
        return (+d3.select(this).attr('y') - gScale(ind - i))
      } else if (arrLen > i && i > ind) {
        gScale.domain([0, arrLen - ind - 1])
        return (+d3.select(this).attr('y') + gScale(i - ind))
      } else {
        return (d3.select(this).attr('y'))
      }
    });
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oguzhanogreden/96o9x5kh/8/). It is rather hard to create/observe the problem here. You will simply have to brush your cursor up and down for a while.

---

What I have tried:

- I've tried using the interrupt signal. However, when I create a log to see how it works exactly, I realized I can create the problem without invoking interrupt signal. Although I do not completely understand how interrupt signal works, I think the solution is not there.
- Storing the original location of a bar and always passing that variable to Event B is an option but it doesn't sound like the most elegant solution.

---

Any leads toward a solution will be much appreciated!

Comment: When A2 starts, select all bars, change pointer-events to `none` and change it back again to `all` when A2 finishes.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, thanks! First please note a fix of confusion about event names in the question. Below I've used new names. Your suggestion helped partially, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oguzhanogreden/96o9x5kh/12). However a similar problem occurs when A2 starts while A1 is running. I guess if scroll is fast enough B1 does not start. You can reproduce this in the last JSFiddle link, again easier on local. I have tried to edit A1 in a similar way, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oguzhanogreden/acw1a6e3/), but it somehow prevents the rest of the changes. Any ideas?

Comment: An update for future reference. Here is why the earlier suggestion doesn't work with mouseover. Setting pointer-events to none for the selection within foo() of selection.on('mouseover', foo()) sends a mouseout signal. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/oguzhanogreden/07ux9aLw/) is a simple example to demonstrate this.

Comment: You are right. That's why I tried to set the pointer events to "none" only inside the "mouseout"... But also without success.